# Power supply (LED driver) specs: "setup", "rise time" meaning?

Tags: power-supply, led-driver

What exactly is meant by the terms "setup" and "rise time" in these specs:

Does it only influence switching at the AC primary side?

I'll use this for a refrigerator light, so it will always be powered.

[image]

Comment: I put some ??? at a 60W refrigerator LED light though. You growing arctic lettuce in there?

Comment: :)  A 2m LED strip (5630) I believe is 48W..

Comment: No, seriously, is it that your LED supplier is crappy, or that you're talking about a 16m2 walk-in freezer? At 115lm/W (verified) my 28m2 primary lab uses 44W of LED light, excluding the microscope lighting and incidental spot-lighting.

Comment: Honestly I've not had these strips before, so I may well be mistaken on the choice. Please elaborate what LED-strips you think would suit best, and how the 5630s would appear. It's a corner-fridge, about 1m^2. I'll run a single strip from top to bottom. Warm-white, with waterproof covering.

Comment: If you need more than 3W of LED light for a fridge, it's very likely you're doing something wrong, regardless of what strip or type of LED. Maybe a tiny bit more if you add lights to each shelve, I'd estimate I might use 0.75W per shelve at 6 shelves in my fridge, but that'd be pretty much the upper limit.

Comment: I believe [this example](http://www.instructables.com/id/Upgrade-Your-Refrigerator-Lighting/) uses 3528s 60leds/m, so about 18W here. I'm not sure if it's "wrong", but certainly looks like one strip at 9W would be enough. Perhaps 30leds/m at 4.5W is still enough, as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

according to the manual

> Setup time is the time taken for the electronic control to become functional, i.e it's input, control loop are ready to be functional, so that it can start output
>
> Rise time is the time to get a steady state output from the time the device  setup time is completed and started outputting the power.

The manual had stated this time at normal load and full load

You had to sum this timing which is the total delay between when you switch it on and the device start outputting the power

Comment: So the rise time would not be applicable to switching the secondary off/on, but only when switching the primary?